# AWS SNS publish success but SOME messages not logged in Cloudwatch

Tags: php, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

We're publishing messages using the SnsClient method from aws-sdk-php - but not all the messages we successfully publish are being logged to Cloudwatch.

For example for a recent batch of 100 messages, all which had a result statusCode of 200 on publishing - only 55 are made it to the Cloudwatch logs.

All these published message have MessageIds of course, in the response, but only roughly half of these messageIds exist in the Cloudwatch logs.

I'm at a loss as to why this is, or how it could be?

Answer (score 0):

aws-sdk-php publishes messages one by one , please check if the whole process is getting completed this can be verified by checking random sent messages

Like 1st time if you run 100 and 55 gets published second time 65 then the error is probably this

2nd cause can be that messages are duplicate and getting batched

3rd some error with the access policy

Comment: Thanks for the comments! As we have messageIds and statusCode 200 on all messages from the sending side - this I assume means the process is completed for all 100 messages?
Duplicate, I did notice 2 duplicate numbers in the batch, do you perhaps have a reference to where AWS docs talk about duplicate handling?